# How can I prevent Desktop Users from accessing any online website?

Tags: ubuntu, security

How can I prevent Desktop Users from accessing any online website in Ubuntu? I tried `127.0.0.1` * in /etc/hosts but it didn't do the trick.

Please note that I need to keep `http://localhost` fully functional.

Answer (score 3):

Options. Options.

1. just ifdown the eth0 interface.
2. iptables as suggested above. better to use:

```
 iptables -A output -p tcp --dport 80 ! --destination 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

as suggested by @hlovdal.

Actually i think both options are very crippling to the system... Is there a reason that we can know why you need the proposed changes? Maybe we can have some easier changes if we know more about your need...

Answer (score 1):

Use IPTables to block all outgoing traffic.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

edit:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport www -j DROP
```

should block all outgoing web traffic (http requests).

Comment: It seems to be working but... 1. How can I reverse the line of code when needed to have the internet working again? 2. In my host file, I have example.com pointed to 127.1.1.0, how can I access it while having the sites blocked? 3. I see www mentioned, does that mean that sites without www may work?! Thanks.

Comment: @emurad: In the command shown, "www" is the port (80). In a URL "www" is simply a hostname. (Almost) no relation.

Comment: Probably better to use `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport www ! --destination 127.0.0.1 -j DROP`

Comment: The "standard" name for 80 is `http`, not `www` - would cause less confusion.